# Pimcore - Related Object Values not getting

Tags: object, pimcore

Hi i am working on pimcore project.

I have **Product Class** which stores product details.

In Product details I have one field **manufacturer** which is refer another **class Manufacturer**.

**Using custom plugin save event i am getting both Product and Manufacturer data.**

But when i try with cron job i am **not getting Related (Manufacturer) object** values.

**Below is the code which is i am using to get object details.**

```
$list = new Object_Product_List();
$list->setCondition('o_id = ?', $objectId);
foreach($list as $list_data)
        {
            $productdata = (array)($list_data);
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($productdata);
            exit;
        }
```

I am getting output like below.

```
Array
(
    [o_classId] => 15
    [o_className] => Product
    [name] => WS-KD WALL SHELVES
    [sku] => HWS-KD-36
    [enable] => 1
    [visibility] => 4
    [manufacturer] =>  // But this value is empty not getting Manufacturer value.
    ...........
    ......... So on
)
```

Please help me where do i made mistake. How to get related object values ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why did you used product list when you try get only one element? O_id is unique value. You can get the product by using getter:

```
Product::getById($objectId);
```

When creating a class, you checked the 'lazy loading' options at the manufacture field?

Comment: No i am trying to get all my product it not one element but it have thousands of products. But yes i have checked lazy loading options is checked. I have un-checked it and it works well. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: thanks once again !!! just because of lazy loading option is checked i am unable to get the value.  I have un-checked it and it works well . Can you please give more idea why that is happening

Comment: If you use 'lazy loading' you have to use setters and getters: "Be Careful - Use Getters and Setters!
$object->multihref = null;
Will not work to clear the list of elements in the multihref when lazy loading ist activated. If the value of an object or multihref data type is null, for Pimcore this means that the data of this field has not been loaded an that it is not to be touched when saving the object."

Comment: ok so as per your opinion we need to unchecked lazy loading option right ?

Comment: If you have a large site and you need to optimize you site, it's best to have 'lazy loading' enabled, but then you need to use getters and setters. However, if you are building a small service and you want to have all the attributes available with the product object, you need to uncheck 'lazy loading' options

Comment: Thanks for the details comments. Actually i am not using pimcore frontend part. I just do sync with other system . So is it good if i disabled lazy loading option ?

Comment: Is there any example how to fetch data if lazy loading option is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a getter to get the manufacturer object.

Something like $list_data->getManufacturer() should work.

Also have a look at the docs:

```
//get a related object
```

`$relationObject = $relation->getObject();`

https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Objects/Object_Classes/Data_Types/Relation_Types.html

Comment: Thanks your answer is also helpful. I am getting the value via get method.